# User context getting null while calling web API from another microservice function

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

I am facing an issue with passing user context between two microservices using a web API.

I am calling one web API from my function which has the current user context, but while calling that web API using *httpClient* in .NET Core, I am getting user context null in another microservice.

Below is the code I am using to call the web API from the function.

```
var requestParams = await new StreamReader(httpRequest.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, requestParams);
```

And I am using context builder to get current user context for the API, but at that point user context is getting null.

```
var context = await contextBuilder.Build(userConfig, request);
```

This is how I am reading context for that web API. If I directly call this API from [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info) or UI then I am getting user context, but the only issue is with calling it from any function from another microservice.

Comment: You also  need to forward the headers where the authentication information lies.

Comment: How ? I tried that already but still not getting success. Can you provide working example of it ?

Comment: Something like [this](https://thecodeblogger.com/2021/05/25/request-header-propagation-in-net-core-web-applications/)

Comment: Just food for thought: Why does your second service, that is apparently not public-facing, need user context? Your first service in this case functions as proxy, it already should have evaluated, whether a user can perform an operation or not. Not a user asks the second service, but the first one. It could authenticate as a service (same trust boundary) and just pass userId or whaterver. The second service would just do what the first one asked of it.